# How to scroll down the scroll bar which in DIV tags with in my web page

Tags: javascript, selenium

I have a requirement on may that, i need to work the scroll bar which in  tag on my page. See attached. 
To access main scroll bar, i can execute java script code - `window.scrollBy()`, but how do i access the inner scroll bar which is DIV tag.

Note : Inner scroll bar is not in frame, also not in separate window on the page.

See attached.

Comment: And where is attached?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to test the scrolling mechanism or access an object off screen by scrolling to it?

To access an object by scrolling you can use the "locationOnceScrolledIntoView" method on the element

If you are trying to test the scrolling mechanism, then unless the scrolling is a bespoke implementation, I would advise against it. You would simply be proving a browser can scroll, which has been tested many times before!